# Parse error in sudoers file

Tags: sudo, ansible, init.d

I've created a user called `kafka` to whom I am trying to give a sudo access to run only `/etc/init.d/kafka` commands.

I added the following entry to `/etc/sudoers.d/kafka` via Ansible:

`kafka ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/kafka`

However, this breaks sudo completely with the following error:

> /etc/sudoers.d/kafka: syntax error near line 1
>       sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/kafka near line 1
>       sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
>       sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Here's the full Ansible snippet:

```
- name: Create kafka user's group
  group:
    name: "{{ kafka_group }}"
    state: present

- name: Create kafka user
  user:
    name: "{{ kafka_user }}"
    state: present
    group: "{{ kafka_group }}"
    shell: /bin/bash

- name: Set up password-less sudo for kafka user
  copy:
    content: "{{ kafka_user }} ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/{{ kafka_service_name }}"
    dest: "/etc/sudoers.d/{{ kafka_user }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0440
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *"sudo: parse error in ..."* originating from `/etc/sudoers`  or any of the files included with either the `#include <filename>` or `#includedir <path>` directives may be caused by a missing new-line on the last entry in that file.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `copy` module is probably not the best choice to handle `/etc/sudoers` with Ansible.

The [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module has an option to validate the file before saving. It is also easier to remove the line, etc with that module.

The [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html#examples) contains an example how to use it.

```
- name: Set up password-less sudo for kafka user
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/sudoers state=present regexp='^%{{ kafka_user }} ALL\=' line='%{{ kafka_user }} ALL= NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/{{ kafka_service_name }}' validate='visudo -cf %s'
```