# Sudo parse error while running any sudo command

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

The following error is triggered when I run `sudo apt update`

```
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/README: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/README near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

README

```
#
# As of Debian version 1.7.2p1-1, the default /etc/sudoers file created on
# installation of the package now includes the directive:
#
#   #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
#
# This will cause sudo to read and parse any files in the /etc/sudoers.d
# directory that do not end in '~' or contain a '.' character.
#
# Note that there must be at least one file in the sudoers.d directory (this
# one will do), and all files in this directory should be mode 0440.
#
# Note also, that because sudoers contents can vary widely, no attempt is
# made to add this directive to existing sudoers files on upgrade.  Feel free
# to add the above directive to the end of your /etc/sudoers file to enable
# this functionality for existing installations if you wish!
#
# Finally, please note that using the visudo command is the recommended way
# to update sudoers content, since it protects against many failure modes.
# See the man page for visudo for more information.
#
```

Comment: `cat` that thing, show us what it tells?

Comment: i have updated the question with the content

Comment: The "Related" aside nav hints me https://serverfault.com/a/791949/178024, I wonder if fixes your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [uprego](https://serverfault.com/users/178024/uprego) the answer for the question : [Parse error in sudoers file](https://serverfault.com/a/791949/178024) fixed the problem